# How can we see "Previous Page Result" if user go from one page to another & another

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Suppose I have an application in which user searching an item & then search that item category , subcategory & availability in country. Or next he search another item **"So now I want to set a button(See Previous result) & by clicking on them he checked all his previous searched result. "** Same as all browser back button works.

So kindly suggest me how can I do that. Any suggestion really appreciate.

Comment: You can store in session variables...

Comment: I am talking about all the page content!

Comment: why you want to store all contents?? doesn't the search keyword/category and type of navigation is enough??

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page

Comment: @gnanz, Actually its need of my application that user can go back to his 'previous search result' same as our browser work, when we click on back & forward arrow then it shows all the previous pages.

Comment: you mean like `window.history.back()` and `window.history.forward()` js method?

Comment: @gnanz >> absolutely right! it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack()
{
window.history.back()
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```

**The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list.
This is the same as clicking the Back button or history.go(-1).**

Answer (score 0):

You can store value to browser sessions and reload the page if session have value then get from session or from your search result.

Answer (score 0):

You can access browser history from javascript using `history` object

```
window.history.back()
```

will bring you one step backward(previous page) and

```
window.history.forward()
```

can access next page from there.

`length` will returns the number of URLs in the history list.

Example:

```
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script> 

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```